# Collision Objects with smoke or dust IOS

Tags: ios, animation

I have add a bounce effect to a `UILabel`, but I want add an explotion effect when it reach the bottom of the bounds. Does anybody know how to add this last effect.

Comment: create the gif in photoshop and use it in the imageview.

Comment: I have try this http://www.raywenderlich.com/6063/uikit-particle-systems-in-ios-5-tutorial but does not work. I want to know if is there is anyway to archive this using swift. Is like object fall down and dust rise because of the collision.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just in case, I resolve this by creating a custom SKScene:

class MyScene: SKScene {

```
override init(size: CGSize) {
    super.init(size: size)
    self.backgroundColor = SKColor(red: 0.15, green: 0.15, blue: 0.3, alpha: 1)
    let sklbl: SKLabelNode = SKLabelNode(fontNamed: "Chalkduster")
    sklbl.text = "hello world !!"
    sklbl.fontSize = 30
    sklbl.position = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(self.frame), CGRectGetMidY(self.frame))
    self.addChild(sklbl)

    //return self
}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
}

func newExplosion (posX:CGFloat, posY:CGFloat) -> SKEmitterNode {
    let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("MyParticle", ofType: "sks")
    let emitter: SKEmitterNode = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObjectWithFile(path!) as! SKEmitterNode

    emitter.position = CGPointMake (posX,posY)
    emitter.name = "explosion"
    emitter.targetNode = self.scene
    emitter.numParticlesToEmit = 1000
    emitter.zPosition = 2.0
    return emitter
}
override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
    for ( index, t ) in touches.enumerate() {
        let p:CGPoint = t.locationInNode(self)
        self.addChild(self.newExplosion(p.x, posY: p.y))
    }
}
override func update(currentTime: NSTimeInterval) {
    /* S e llama antes de que cada frame es rendered*/
} }
```

After that I have to create a sks file with effect of smoke called MyParticle.sks

Then on my controller I have added a view and set it the class "SKView".

Then I linked that view as

```
  @IBOutlet weak var blurLoading: SKView!
```

and add this element also:

```
   var amiterlayer: CAEmitterLayer = CAEmitterLayer()
```

finally on the viewload event I add:

```
   self.blurLoading.showsFPS = true
   self.blurLoading.showsNodeCount = true
   let s:MyScene = MyScene (size: self.blurLoading.bounds.size)
   s.scaleMode = SKSceneScaleMode.AspectFill
   self.blurLoading.presentScene (s)
```

And the effect work when touching the screen, if you want to call ondemand just do: self.blurLoading.scene.newExplosion (x,y).

It works !!